# python call of ffmpeg misses target file parameter

Tags: windows, python-3.x, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm writing a python GUI for ffmpeg. When calling ffmpeg via subprocess it runs fine as long as the command is like

```
subprocess.Popen([ffmpeg_converter,
        '-i',file,
        target_file
        ])
```

But when I do the same call with ffmpeg arguments it fails with 
"At least one output file must be specified":

```
option_string = '-q:a 4'
subprocess.Popen([ffmpeg_converter,
        '-i',file,
        option_string,
        target_file
        ])
```

It even recognizes the options but does not see the target file. I even replaced the actual target file with someting simple like "test.mp3" but still the same error. Any ideas? (I'm on windows with python 3.3.)

The complete console output is:

```
    ffmpeg version N-57781-g0610d6e Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov  1 2013 18:01:35 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 49.100 / 52. 49.100
  libavcodec     55. 40.101 / 55. 40.101
  libavformat    55. 20.105 / 55. 20.105
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 90.100 /  3. 90.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Trailing options were found on the commandline.
Input #0, flac, from 'c:\script\python\testdata\source\01. Es geht los.flac':
  Metadata:
    ARTIST          : Olivia Trummer Trio
    TITLE           : Es geht los
    ALBUM           : Westwind
    DATE            : 2008
    track           : 01
    GENRE           : Jazz
    COMMENT         : EAC FLAC -8
  Duration: 00:06:27.25, bitrate: 834 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: What is the actual ffmpeg command (and complete console output) that results from your code?

Comment: Have you tried passing in a fully constructed string instead of a list?

Comment: @Ethan Furman: Yes, I triedto construct a string but ran in even more trouble since file names with spaces need extra quoting and this results in a quite complex string composition in python. I tried someting like
call_string = r"'" + ffmpeg_converter + r"' -i '" + os.path.normcase(file) + r"' " + option_string + r" '" + os.path.normcase(target_file) + r"'"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass `-q:a 4` as separate values `-q:a`, `4`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

subprocess.Popen([ffmpeg_converter,
        '-i',file,
        '-q:a', '4'
        target_file
        ])

You are passing your option string as one argument instead of two.